# Issue with acquireTokenSilentAsync : Refresh Token

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, azure-active-directory

I want to use the Azure Active Directory for authorization in my Ionic App
I'm successfully able to get the accessToken from Azure AD
but after the token get expired I have called the acquireTokenSilentAsync and I'm getting this below error
code:

AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED

message:

> Refresh token is failed and prompt is not allowed

I'm using [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) cordova plugin 
**azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova**

Please help guys.

Comment: Did you register the app in AAD as a native app? I'm not sure if this is needed in this scenario, but have you enabled implicit grant flow?

Comment: yes, I have registered the App in the AD and also I have enabled the implicit flow.

Comment: Yeah but was it registered as a **native app**?

Comment: yes, I have registered app as a Native in AD